# Sympy: integrate() strange output

Tags: python, sympy

I'm just learning how to use sympy and I have tried a simple integration of a sin function. When the argument of `sin()` has a constant phase constant the output of `integrate()` gives the same value whatever is the phase: 0

```
from sympy import *
w = 0.01
phi = 0.3
k1 = integrate(sin(w*x), (x, 0.0, 10.0))
k2 = integrate(sin(w*x + 0.13), (x, 0.0, 10.0))
k3 = integrate(sin(w*x + phi),(x, 0.0, 10.0))
k1, k2, k3

(0.499583472197429, 0, 0)
```

Can somebody explain me why ?

Comment: How did you define `x`?

Comment: I can reproduce this for a variety of `w` and `phi`, even for indefinite integrals. E.g., `integrate(sin(0.7*x + 0.1), x)` gives `0`. Looks like a bug to me!

Comment: It seems has rather a lot of integral bugs. (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/labels/integrals) Still it integrates correctly if `w` is set as `symbol`

Comment: It seems to be nonzero only when the phase is an integer multiple of pi. Very odd.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but it also seems a bug for me !.

Comment: @user1259970: i just saw this old question again... Does any of the answers solved the issue and if so, could you then accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code in the development version of SymPy and I got `(0.499583472197429, 1.78954987094131, 3.42754951227208)`. So it seems the bug will be fixed in the next version.

It also looks like this bug is in Python 2 only. When I use Python 3, even with the latest stable version (0.7.6.1) I get the same answer.

Comment: Thanks asmeuser. I am not sure if this is a bug or not because I have checked and verified that I'm using Python 3.4.4 (on Anaconda 2.1.0) and the sympy version is 0.7.6.1 according to init_session(). I have tried the "SymPy Live Shell" interactive system on the [SymPy web site](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/printing.html) and once again I've got the same result:(0.499583472197429,0,0)

Comment: Can you try the sympy version from GitHub?

Comment: Yes, the sympy version from GitHub (SymPy 0.7.7.dev) fix the problem. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a bug. A workaround solution could be to get a symbolic expression of your integral first (which seems to work fine), then evaluate it for each set of parameters at the upper and lower bound and calculate the difference:

```
import sympy as sp
x, w, phi = sp.symbols('x w phi')

# integrate function symbolically
func = sp.integrate(sp.sin(w * x  + phi), x)

# define your parameters
para = [{'w': 0.01, 'phi': 0., 'lb': 0., 'ub': 10., 'res': 0.},
        {'w': 0.01, 'phi': 0.13, 'lb': 0., 'ub': 10., 'res': 0.},
        {'w': 0.01, 'phi': 0.3, 'lb': 0., 'ub': 10., 'res': 0.}]

# evaluate your function for all parameters using the function subs
for parai in para:
    parai['res'] = func.subs({w: parai['w'], phi: parai['phi'], x: parai['ub']})
    -func.subs({w: parai['w'], phi: parai['phi'], x: parai['lb']})
```

After this, `para` looks then as follows:

```
[{'lb': 0.0, 'phi': 0.0, 'res': 0.499583472197429, 'ub': 10.0, 'w': 0.01},
 {'lb': 0.0, 'phi': 0.13, 'res': 1.78954987094131, 'ub': 10.0, 'w': 0.01},
 {'lb': 0.0, 'phi': 0.3, 'res': 3.42754951227208, 'ub': 10.0, 'w': 0.01}]
```

which seems to give reasonable results for the integration which are stored in `res`

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I verified that developing the expression in sin() and cos() symbolically and evaluating at the end worked fine, but I was really surprised of such behavior and I didn't understand why.

Comment: Ok, yes, I understand the confusion. As asmeurer says below, it seems to happen only in Python 2 and the bug will be fixed in the next version. Thanks for pointing out this bug; I use sympy from time to time and will now be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend using `numpy` for numerical integration?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> w = 0.01
>>> phi = 0.3
>>> dt = 0.01
>>> t = 2*np.pi*np.arange(0,1,dt)
>>> np.sum( np.sin(t)*dt)
-1.0733601507606494e-17
>>> np.sum( np.sin(t+ phi)*dt)
2.5153490401663703e-17
```

These numbers are basically close to 0.  The exact number is an artifact of our choice of mesh `dt` and shift `phi` (as well as the accuracy of `np.sin`)

To be more consistent with your example:

```
>>> t = np.arange(0,10,dt)
>>> w = 0.01
>>> phi = 0.3
>>> np.sum( np.sin(w*t)*dt)
0.4990843046978698
>>> np.sum( np.sin(w*t + phi)*dt)
3.4270800187375658
>>> np.sum( np.sin(w*t + 0.13)*dt)
1.7890581525454512
```

As quoted in [Integrating in Python using Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569670/integrating-in-python-using-sympy) **it's a bad idea to use a symbolic library for numerical work**

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is not my intention to use sympy for solving numerical problems just to learn how to use sympy and the example is so innocent that I'm really surprised.